# Съезжает фон на сайте

Tags: html, css

Когда приближаю в браузере, картинка съезжает вправо, как пофиксить?

```css
.container2
 {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 1920px;
  
 }
  
  #banner
 {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 470px;
  background-image: url("images/banner.jpg");
  background-position: center;
 }
```

```html
<div id="banner" class="container2">
  <span>текст текст</span>
  <span1>текст текст</span1>
 </div>
```

Comment: всегда интересовал вопрос: а зачем собсно так делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

когда ты приближаешь, экран становится меньше (в пиксилях), у тебя container2 вообще на всю ширину растянут, вот и получается что она едит, вообще сайты не предназначены чтобы их просто увеличивать, но фиксится это медиа запросом (в css: `@media`). Вообще он используется для адаптации, но работает он так, что ты задаёшь другие стили под другие размеры, получается что это исправит проблему в приближении, когда экран будет меньше.
почитай документацию про [@media](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как вы решаете проблемы съехавших блоков, когда пиксели неправильно округляются при зуме. Есть ли какие-то мысли на этот счёт? Просто media не всегда помогает, потому что пиксели становятся другими.

Comment: @Pavel Grishaev если честно мне не приходилось решать подобной проблемы, тут надо смотреть по ситуации, для чего он нужен, может проще будет с помощью js что-то настроить или сам объект больше сделать, псевдоклассы и тд и тп, к сожалению тут помочь не могу(